# Music doesn't play in application (javax.sound.sampled.Clip)

Tags: java, javasound

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
public class PlayAudio{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

    File wavFile = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Wate.wav");
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(wavFile);
    Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(ais);
    clip.start();
 }
}
```

My question is: Why does the music not play in this application? (IDE is Eclipse)

Comment: 1) Is the path name correct? 2) Do you have some speakers? 3) Do you have the speakers on? 4) Check the volume.

Comment: what i feel is that program exits before playback starts. Try adding `Thread.sleep(10000)` after `clip.start()`, may be that could help.

Comment: I dont think there is any error.Is the duration of the clip 0.001 sec?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your main application thread exits before the sound clip can play. You could call `Thread.sleep` with an arbitrary timeout after `clip.start()`, but better to create a dedicated `Thread` to keep track of the audio data as it plays:

```
public class PlayAudio {

    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    boolean stopPlayback = false;

    public void playAudio(File soundFile) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
            IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        new Thread(new PlayThread()).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        new PlayAudio().playAudio(new File("myclip.wav"));
    }

    class PlayThread implements Runnable {
        byte soundBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
                sourceDataLine.start();
                int cnt;
                while ((cnt = audioInputStream.read(soundBuffer, 0,
                        soundBuffer.length)) != -1 && stopPlayback == false) {
                    if (cnt > 1) {
                        sourceDataLine.write(soundBuffer, 0, cnt);
                    }
                }
                sourceDataLine.drain();
                sourceDataLine.close();
                stopPlayback = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'quick-n-dirty' method of prolonging the `main(String[])` by showing a `JOptionPane` can be seen on the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info). +1 for your approach.